# Correct way to remove the box of checkbox completely in API 16 and lower

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

I've got a problem with hiding the box of my `CheckBox`. My `CheckBox` looks like this at the moment:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/favoritesBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:button="@null"
    android:tag="1"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text="@string/details_tags_favs" />
```

The only problem here is, the `button=@null` is removing its style and its not completely gone. Because of that, my `text` is not centered but moved to the right (by box size).

Is there a smooth way to get rid of it completely in API 16 and lower?

Comment: u want to make completely invisible ur checkbox

Comment: I want the BOX itself to be completely gone, but text to remain visible.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue, and while I'm experimenting this, may I know why you don't use other widget than `CheckBox`? (perhaps `ToggleButton`?)

Comment: Because even tho I set `background=@android:color/transparent` the `View` itself is quite big on `wrap_context`.
And I have a view below it that is animating when the `CheckBox` is clicked. With `ToggleView` its really far away so it looks quite bad.

Comment: Ok, I solved it - you also have to set `background="@android:color/transparent` on `CheckBox` and the view will be gone. 
Thanks for help @AndrewT. I solved it with RubberDuck debugging thanks to you xD

Comment: That's great! Feel free to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it :)

Comment: Could you have used a `CheckedTextView` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a little help from from Andrew T. with my RubberDuck debugging I found solution for this problem.

What you have to do is set `background="@android:color/transparent` on `CheckBox` and the invisible box will be gone from your `View`.

So my new `CheckBox` looks like this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/favoritesBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:tag="1"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text="@string/details_tags_favs" />
```

Comment: This answer didn't work on API 16 for me. 
I added `app:buttonCompat="@null"` and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Following property work for me.

```
android:button="@null"
```